# Help w/ password

Tags: password

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reset a lost Administrative (root) password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password)

I can not remember my password as I have automatic log in.  I need to change all my previous passwords (not because of anything Ubuntu did) How can I find out what it is, so I can change it?  Please help me with this.  I thank you in advance.